# HALF_PTR Windows data type

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, types

The VS documentation states

> Half the size of a pointer. Use within a structure that contains a pointer and two small fields.
>
> [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types)

What, exactly, is this type and how is it used, if ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use within a structure that contains a pointer and two small fields.

This means that in the following structure, no padding is required:

```
struct Example {
    void* pointer;
    HALF_PTR one;
    HALF_PTR two;
};
```

Of course, this is only relevant if the size of `HALF_PTR` (32 bits on a 64-bit system, 16 bits on a 32-bit system) is sufficient to hold the intended values.

Comment: Forgot about the padding bit. +1.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Why does it need a union? You can be sure here that `sizeof(struct Example)` is `2*sizeof(void*)`. No need for a union here.

Comment: @Billy: well, you'd use HALF_PTR to access the parts of the pointer.  Like you did in your answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The documentation doesn't indicate that one should use `HALF_PTR` to access the parts of a pointer—after all, what would you gain from splitting up a pointer in two parts? I think the quotation indicates a usage like the one in my example.

Comment: How do you propose to initialize them?

Comment: how are there any padding if you use 2 pointers? `struct Example { void* p1; void* p2; }` has exactly the same size and the same alignment in both 32 and 64-bit Windows

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/replace-a-set-of-pointers-with-a-base-pointer-to-reduce-data-bloat/) on Intel's site, and it they suggest using it in a context where you have a class with many pointer members, along with a 32-bit offset to get the actual address, to cut down on data bloat of a class. The article specifically talks about the Itanium platform because it uses 64-bit pointers instead of 32-bit, but I assume the problem/solution to the problem would be the same on any system using 64-bit pointers.

So in short, it seems to suggest that it can be used if you, for example, wish to reduce the memory footprint of a class?

Comment: the link has rot which makes the answer invalid. That's why [link only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/230282). And that "32-bit offset" is just an offset and not a HALF_PTR where two halves combined into a single pointer

Answer (score 2):

Note: Anonymous structs are not standard, but MSVC takes them:

```
union
{
    int * aPointer
    struct
    {
        HALF_PTR lowerBits;
        HALF_PTR upperBits;
    };
} myvar; //You can be assured this union is sizeof(int *)
```

If you're thinking they're not too terribly useful, you would be right.

Answer (score 0):

I guess *“Use within a structure that contains a pointer and two small fields”* means a pointer constructed from two HALF_PTRs along with two other non-pointer small data fields

```
struct Packed {
    HALF_PTR low_ptr;
    HALF_PTR high_ptr;
    SMALL one;
    SMALL two;
};
struct Padded {
    void *ptr;
    SMALL one;
    SMALL two;
};
```

- On 32-bit Windows:

  - When `SMALL` is `char`: `sizeof(Packed) == 6` but `sizeof(Padded) = 8`
  - When `SMALL` is `short`: the size of both structs are 8, but the alignment requirement for the former is just 2 compared to 4
- On 64-bit Windows:

  - When `SMALL` is `char`: `sizeof(Packed) == 10` but `sizeof(Padded) = 16`
  - When `SMALL` is `short`: `sizeof(Packed) == 12` but `sizeof(Padded) = 16`
  - When `SMALL` is `int`: same size, but reduced alignment requirement like above

This is unlike [Philipp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3344040/995714) where the size and alignment of the struct is exactly the same whether splitting into half or not

```
struct Example1 {
    void* pointer;
    HALF_PTR one;
    HALF_PTR two;
};
struct Example2 {
    void* pointer;
    void* one_two;
};
```

Both have alignment equal to the size of the pointer, and size of 2 pointers