# How to map HALF_PTR in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, types, native

I am currently modelling a type conversion mechanism which converts native ([Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to .NET

**Example:**

```
HANDLE = System.IntPtr
HDC = System.IntPtr
WORD = System.UInt16
```

`INT_PTR` is 32bit/64bit on their respective machines, so in .NET thats a `System.IntPtr`

`HALF_PTR` (and others) are 16bit/32bit on their respective 32bit/64bit machines...

so how would I model `HALF_PTR` in .NET - If possible?

I guess another way of looking at this is: *Is There a "short" pointer equivalent for C#...something like ShortPtr?*

Comment: Use of HALF_PTR? Because if it's only for marshaling data for one or two methods, perhaps it's faster to create some proxies for the methods.

Comment: @xanatos, do you think that in this respect, I could just omit this type of "short" pointer from my code and warn the user of its use instead?

Comment: In years of using the Win32 API I never met `HALF_PTR`, that seems to be used only in [very specialized cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343779/half-ptr-windows-data-type); I don't even think it is actually used in any public API, since Googling "HALF_PTR site:microsoft.com" doesn't give any result relative to a `struct` or function. Thus, I think it could be safe to just ignore it, and provide a warning in the rare instance where it could show up, explaining that a `struct`/function that uses it requires manual intervention.

Comment: @series0ne Show us the APIs you want to convert! :-) Otherwise it becomes an abstract problem. There are often multiple solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-issue.  It is declared in Basetsd.h but it isn't actually used in *any* winapi declaration.  The odds you'll actually ever run into it are very close to zero.

If you must, it is only defined for programs that target 64-bit processors.  It maps a 64-bit pointer to two 32-bit halves.  You'll get the same by converting an IntPtr to UInt64 and get the two UInt32 parts with `& 0xffffffff` and `>> 32`.

Comment: I had a feeling you'd know the answer to this. I found some comments you'd written on another site regarding pointers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible in .NET (Microsoft .NET implementation, I mean). In Mono it's possible to conditionally redirect the reference to a dll based on the current architecture, so you could create two `HalfPtr` `struct`s, one for 32 bits system and one for 64 bits system, but on .NET this isn't possible. Conditional compilation (`#if`) is only at compile time, not at runtime, and you would need something similar but at runtime, and automatic marshaling isn't powerful enough to do "conditionals".

On Mono:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="myhalfptrdll">
        <dllentry dll="myhalfptrdll32.so" wordsize="32" />
        <dllentry dll="myhalfptrdll64.so" wordsize="64" />
    </dllmap>
</configuration>
```

The only possible solution for the rare cases is to make 2 PInvoke `extern`s that "point" one to an `int` and one to a `short` and that are selected by some static constructor.